# Pycharm Type-Hinting of Functions isn't marking incorrect parameters as such

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

Pycharm is incorrectly issuing no warning when passing certain types of parameters into a type hinted function.

```py
# python 3.7.4
# pycharm PyCharm 2019.2 (Professional Edition)
# Build #PY-192.5728.105, built on July 23, 2019
from typing import List, Union

def test_func(x: Union[str, List[str]]):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        print("no problem string")
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        if all([type(xi) == str for xi in x]):
            print("no problem list[str]")
        else:
            print("problem list")
    else:
        print("problem type")

test_func(x="x") # <no problem string>, Pycharm correctly issues no warning
test_func(x=["x", "y"]) # <no problem list>, Pycharm correctly issues no warning
test_func(x=["x", ["x"]]) # <problem list>, Pycharm incorrectly issues no warning
test_func(x=["x", [2]])  # <problem list>, Pycharm incorrectly issues no warning
test_func(x=2) # <problem type>, Pycharm correctly issues a warning
```

Pycharm should be issuing a warning on calls 3 & 4 of test_func but doesn't. Is this is a known limitation of Pycharm or have I missed something?

<s>Bonus: If it is a known issue of Pycharm is there a you track for it?</s>

edit_1: Created [PY-37549](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37549)

Comment: It's a bug. Inferred type of the passed argument is `List[Union[str, List[int]]]`. Typechecker matches it in the following way: it takes `List[str]` of the expected type and then successfully matches `Union[str, List[int]]` against `str` :(

Comment: Looks like an answer, more than a comment? ;)

Comment: Reported via PY-37549. Thanks for confirming it was a bug.

Also just curious how did you determine what the inferred type of the passed arguments were? 

Why I'm asking:
The issue remains if you remove all function calls except 3; and in fact function call 3 was what I actually stumbled across. Is the typechecker doing something similar here as well? If I were to follow your example: inferring passed argument as List[Union[str, List]] and matching Union[str, List] against str?

Comment: @r-richmond Set caret on passed argument and call `View - Type Info`